# Why is my Mocha reporter double reporting tests?

Tags: javascript, html, mocha.js

I have a custom reporter `doc-output.js` modified from the doc reporter.

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var Base = require('./base')
  , utils = require('../utils');

/**
 * Expose `Doc`.
 */

exports = module.exports = Doc;

/**
 * Initialize a new `Doc` reporter.
 *
 * @param {Runner} runner
 * @api public
 */

function Doc(runner) {
  Base.call(this, runner);

  var self = this
    , stats = this.stats
    , total = runner.total
    , indents = 2;

  function indent() {
    return Array(indents).join('  ');
  }

  runner.on('start', function() {
    console.log('<ul id="mocha-report">');
    ++indents;
  });

  runner.on('suite', function(suite){
    if (suite.root) return;
    ++indents;
    console.log('%s<li class="suite">', indent());
    ++indents;
    console.log('%s<h1>%s</h1>', indent(), utils.escape(suite.title));
    console.log('%s<ul>', indent());
  });

  runner.on('suite end', function(suite){
    if (suite.root) return;
    console.log('%s</ul>', indent());
    --indents;
    console.log('%s</section>', indent());
    --indents;
  });

  runner.on('pass', function(test){
    console.log('<li class="test pass fast">');
    ++indents;
    console.log('%s  <h2 id="pass">%s</h2>', indent(), utils.escape(test.title));
    var code = utils.escape(utils.clean(test.fn.toString()));
    console.log('%s  <pre style="display: none;"><code>%s</code></pre></li>', indent(), code);
  });

  runner.on('fail', function(test, err){
    console.log('<li class="test fail">');
    ++indents;
    // console.log('%s::before', indents());
    console.log('<h2 id="fail">%s</h2>', utils.escape(test.title));
    console.log('%s  <pre class="error">%s</pre>', indent(), utils.escape(err));
    var code = utils.escape(utils.clean(test.fn.toString()));
    console.log('%s  <pre style="display: block;"><code>%s</code></pre></li>', indent(), code);
  });

  runner.on('end', function() {
    --indents;
    console.log('</ul>');
  });
}
```

I'm running Mocha programmatically with the code:

```js
var Mocha = require('mocha');

mocha = new Mocha({
 reporter: 'doc-output',
 ui: 'bdd',
 quiet: true
});

// a file with mocha tests in it
mocha.addFile('./simp');

var write = process.stdout.write;
var output = "";

process.stdout.write = function(str) {
  output += str;
};

mocha.run(function(failures) {
    process.stdout.write = write;
    process.on('exit', function () {
        process.exit(failures);
    });
});
```

When I run it, the output variable is printed in html. It is reporting itself twice.

```html
<div id="mocha">
  &lt;
  <ul id="mocha-report">
    <li class="suite">
      <h1>describe level 1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="suite">
          <h1>describe level 2</h1>
          <ul>
            <li class="test pass fast">
              <h2 id="pass">it first</h2>
              <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');                 done();</code></pre>
            </li>
            <li class="test pass fast">
              <h2 id="pass">it second</h2>
              <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');
                done();</code></pre>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="suite">
          <h1>second nested describe</h1>
          <ul>
            <li class="test pass fast">
              <h2 id="pass">it</h2>
              <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');
              done();</code></pre>
            </li>
            <li class="test fail">
              <h2 id="fail">it should fail</h2>
              <pre class="error">AssertionError: expected 'hello' to be a number</pre>
              <pre style="display: block;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('number');
              done();</code></pre>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
&gt;<!--<ul id="mocha-report"-->
  <li class="suite">
    <h1>describe level 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="suite">
        <h1>describe level 2</h1>
        <ul>
          <li class="test pass fast">
            <h2 id="pass">it first</h2>
            <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');
done();</code></pre>
          </li>
          <li class="test pass fast">
            <h2 id="pass">it second</h2>
            <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');
            done();</code></pre>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="suite">
        <h1>second nested describe</h1>
        <ul>
          <li class="test pass fast">
            <h2 id="pass">it</h2>
            <pre style="display: none;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('string');
            done();</code></pre>
          </li>
          <li class="test fail">
            <h2 id="fail">it should fail</h2>
            <pre class="error">AssertionError: expected 'hello' to be a number</pre>
            <pre style="display: block;"><code>('hello').should.be.a('number');
            done();</code></pre>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    &gt;
  </li>
</div>
```

Also, it inserts random "<" and ">" at the beginning and ends. I'm not sure if this is a related issue.

Why is my test reporting twice? I don't see anything wrong with the reporter.

Oh, and also, I'm calling this in a templating engine using jade. Like so,

```
#{result}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

The < and > were coming from calling #{result} instead of !{result}

The double reporting was coming from spying on process.stdout.write. I was copying std out and spying at the same time, which cause it to report double.